# Host unreachable after docker swarm init

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, windows-server

I have Windows Server 2016 Core(Hyper-V VM). Docker is installed, working and I want to create swarm.

IP config at the beginning:

```
1. Ethernet - 192.168.0.1
2. vEthernet (HSN Internal NIC) - 172.30.208.1
```

Then I run

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.0.1
```

Swarm is created, but I have lost my main IP address. IP config:

```
1. vEthernet (HNS internal NIC) - 172.30.208.1
2. vEthernet (HNS Transparent) - 169.254.225.229
```

Created swarm manager node is not reachable on main address 192.168.0.1. I can't connect to it and swarm workers are not able to join with this IP. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A little late answering this but ... Docker is going to take over your network card when you bring up the Swarm. What I did was use two network cards: one I left alone for Docker to use and the second I used for everything else including virtual machines.

Comment: Does this depend on manager/worker? Because worker nodes work as expected. (I ended up having linux manager nodes and windows worker nodes)

Comment: @MiroslavAdamec :please post your solution as an answer

Comment: Actually it looks like an issue with Windows 2019 release as well ... https://success.docker.com/article/swarm-init-bricks-win

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot use Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows alone to test a multi-node swarm. For single node swarm cluster,

> If you are using Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows to test single-node swarm, simply run docker swarm init with no arguments
>
> However, you can use the included version of Docker Machine to create the swarm nodes (see Get started with Docker Machine and a local VM), then follow the tutorial for all multi-node features

For furthere info read [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#use-docker-for-mac-or-docker-for-windows)

Edit:

Also refer to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/)

Comment: I don't understand. So how can I create swarm on multiple windows servers?